# Activation of the tabs through navigation

Tags: jquery, html, tabs, navigation

I am writing the code as

```
<div class="tslcNav" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="mngPost.html">Manage Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="riskAssesment.html">Risk Assessment</a></li>
                <li><a href="security_setup.html">Security Setup</a></li>
                <li><a href="dataOwner-riskAssessmentCompliance.html"style="visibility: hidden"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Also

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href
                .lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        $(".tslcNav ul li a").each(
                function() {
                    if(pgurl=="dataOwner-riskAssessmentCompliance.html")
                        $("riskAssesment.html").addClass("active");
                    if ($(this).attr("href") == pgurl
                            || $(this).attr("href") == '')
                        $(this).closest('li').addClass("active");
                })          
    });
```

But it is not activating the tab when I am on dataOwner-riskAssessmentCompliance.html page.It should active the tab `riskAssesment.html` when I am on `dataOwner-riskAssessmentCompliance.html` page.What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using wrong selector, you should use `href` with page name like,

```
if(pgurl=="dataOwner-riskAssessmentCompliance.html")
    $("[href='riskAssesment.html']").addClass("active");
```

And I think you want to add `active` class to its parent `li`,

```
$(function() {
    var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href
            .lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    $(".tslcNav ul li a").each(function() {
        if(pgurl=="dataOwner-riskAssessmentCompliance.html"){
            $("[href='riskAssesment.html']").addClass("active")
                                            .closest('li').addClass('active');
        }
        else {
            if ($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr('href') == '')
                $(this).closest('li') // get the closest li
                       .addClass("active"); // add active class to that li
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Instead of closest(li) can we use any other method?Because If I directly land on any page using URL then it is not showing that active tab otherwise it is showing.(Means If I run the project it will show but if I type the URL then it will not show the active tab)

Comment: Code in my answer will only work if your page get refreshed. If you want to make anchor as active then use the same logic for that event.

Answer (score 0):

In order to add class you need to acces the selector using `href` as

```
$("[href='riskAssesment.html']").addClass("active");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need this

```
var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
$('ul.nav > li').removeClass("active");
$("a[href='"+pgurl+"']").parent().addClass("active");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            var url = window.location.toString().split('?');

            $('ul.nav li a').filter(function () {
                if (this.href != '') {
                    if (this.href == url[0]) {
                        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

I hope it helps you.